# How to solve No signature of method: static java.lang.String.parseString() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [testowy]</faultstring>

Tags: java, web-services, groovy, soap, mocking

In soap mock service i want to have dynamic response base on value in request so i create the script but i get error
Failed to dispatch using script; groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.lang.String.parseString() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [testowy]

My script looks that

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
// get arguments 
def invoiceId = Integer.parseInt( holder["//invoiceId"] )
def header1 = String.parseString( holder["//header1"] )
def header2 = String.parseString( holder["//header2"] )
def invoiceNumber = String.parseString( holder["//invoiceNumber"] )
def invoiceOrder = Integer.parseInt( holder["//invoiceOrder"] )


def totalValue = Float.parseFloat( holder["//totalValue"] )
def categoryId = Integer.parseInt( holder["//categoryId"] )
def categoryName = String.parseString( holder["//categoryName"] )
requestContext.result =  invoiceId  header1 invoiceNumber invoiceOrder invoiceDate dueDate totalValue  categoryId categoryName
```

The problem is with String.parseString i didint know why
for every other arguments its ok
can someone explain why i get this error

Comment: there is no such method 'String.parseString(...)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method `String.parseString` in the JDK.  What you want to do is something like the following:

```
def categoryName = holder["//categoryName"]
```

However, I suspect that may even be questionable because `XmlHolder` is a map and `get()` returns an `Object` so it's unknown what that's going to return.  But there is a method that returns a String which is what you're after so you might do this instead:

```
def categoryName = holder.getNodeValue("//categoryName")
```

That [method](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html#getNodeValue-java.lang.String-) seems to take an xpath expression and return the contents of an XML node as a String.